# Error on scalar variable declaration even when the variable is declared

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL statement; when executed in SSMS, it runs ok, but when executed through a scheduler, I get this error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@student_id".

Can I get some help understanding what possibly could be causing this?

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 
(
    TYPE1 nvarchar(256),
    TABLE_ID nvarchar(256)
);

DECLARE @student_id INT
SET @student_id = 1;

WHILE @student_id <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @area NVARCHAR(256)
    
    SET @area = (SELECT AREA 
                 FROM
                     (SELECT
                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AREA ASC) AS NB_ROW,
                          AREA
                      FROM 
                          STUDENT) AS TEMP
                 WHERE NB_ROW = @student_id)        
        
    INSERT INTO TABLE2 (TYPE1, TABLE_ID)
        SELECT 
            TYPE1, TABLE_ID
        FROM 
            TABLE3

    SET @student_id = @student_id + 1
END;
```

Comment: By "scheduler" do you mean Windows scheduler? How are you using it to execute the command? `SQLCMD`? .Net objects in Powershell? Something else?

Comment: As a side note a `WHILE` is a *terribly* inefficient method here; a set-based approach would be significantly more performant.

Comment: what if you do `DECLARE @student_id INT = 1;` and no `SET`

Comment: We are using an app, and it has its own scheduler. We define a task to trigger the sql execution.

Comment: Does your app, by any chance treat semicolons as a batch seperator, rather than a batch seperator?

Comment: @Larnu yes thats the case with the semicolons.

Comment: @T.S. still the same error

Comment: Then there's your problem, your app is interpreting them as batch seperators, and so the variable is no longer declares. Ideally change the batch seperator to `GO`.